# How to configure bundle in Symfony4?

Tags: symfony, configuration, bundle, symfony4

I would like to configure `kucharovic/money-bundle` but from what I can read in README - it tells me to add configuration to `app/config/config.yml` which is the old way of doing things. In Symfony4 I don't have `config.yml` file, configuration is under `config/packages` directory.

How can I configure that bundle under Symfony4 so that bundle recognizes it's configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `config/packages/framework.yaml` or `config/packages/security.yaml`, adds your bundle config file `config/packages/money.yaml`.

Just make sure to set the correct bundle config alias inside it:

```
# config/packages/money.yaml
jk_money: # <-- configuration alias
    # your bundle config
```

It'll be loaded automatically.

Comment: money should actually be jk_money

Comment: As @Cerad mentioned, it should read `jk_money`. See [this](https://github.com/kucharovic/money-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L50).